# Broken files - wrong path to php files when loading contact form in a div (using jquery load function) - what is wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web

Okay, so I'm loading this (it's a contact form) in a div on www.mydomain.com/contact.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#result').load('http://www.mydomain.com/support/contact.php #ticketForm');
      });
</script>
```

It shows the contact form, but there is a captcha picture that isn't loading because the path is wrongly set to www.mydomain.com/captcha.php (shows when I right-click the captcha "broken file" picture) instead of www.mydomain.com/support/captcha.php. Also seems that some of the styling is missing, most likely because of the same problem with a wrong path.

All the files and folders that contact.php needs are located in the www.mydomain.com/support directory and not www.mydomain.com.

How do I fix this problem without moving all the files? I'm no coder so please explain as much as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, you've added #ticketForm in to the load method, which means HTML script blocks in the document being loaded into #result are stripped out and not executed and would explain your CSS and non-loading of capcha image on initial load.

Secondly: How do you intent to capture the data posted? From the appearance, I get the feeling you think that by AJAX'ing the contact.php file, you think when you post the data, AJAX will still continue which is false. I recommend you look at $.post and $.get.

Comment: Thanks very much Richard. Yes, I got it wrong and I now understand that I have wasted a lot of time on something that will never work. I somehow thought that the data would be captured and that it would work like an iframe. 

Wow I suck at this... I will look at $.post (isn't that the secure solution when you handle sensitive data, compared to $.get?) Thanks again - I appreciate.

Comment: $.get and $.post are both insecure, look at SSL for securing your data. - You don't suck, you're learning and we all started somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your comforting words and sorry for my late response. I thought $.post was secure enough for name, email and stuff like that... Yeah, I got a lot to learn. I will have to look into it a bit more - in the meantime I will have to use an iframe. Hope that is secure! I will accept your answer below - you have been helpful. Thanks again for spending time on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, rename the file path accordingly. This will allow the inline execution of the subsequent scripts.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get(  
        'path/to/contact.php', 
        function(responseText){  
            $("#result").html(responseText);  
        }   
    );  
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I replace "get" with "post"? - the information people type into the form is kind of sensitive and post should be more secure than get. Do I also have to use the code I have in my original question or will your code both show the form and capture the data?

Comment: That version, should be used to "get" the results, you should create another version of it, outside of the $(document).ready() state and place it in a function xxx() so when you click submit, you post the details through and get the results after once again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer comment I was replying to go deleted....

> the link to `captcha.php` in `contact.php` is wrong.

actually... based on what he said "It shows the contact form, but there is a captcha picture that isn't loading because the path is wrongly set to www.mydomain.com/captcha.php (shows when I right-click the captcha "broken file" picture) instead of www.mydomain.com/support/captcha.php", this answer is correct, but without attempting to fix it.  Within your `contact.php`, change the `captcha.php` link to `support/captcha.php`

Comment: I didn't delete it, I have no priviledges, and I understand your concern for the path, but, with Javascript and Capcha's already being tricky enough, if their subsequent script files are not being executed, so based on the code he was using, he needs to fix that first before your answer could have been the end result in the fix. - I wasn't discouraging your answer, I highlighted in my comment on his question the flaw of what he did with the load() method.

Comment: @RichardDickinson I wasn't talking about your answer.  There was another answer here for about 5 minutes that I was attempting to respond to. ^^  Your answer I thought was decent, as `.load` isn't all that great to begin with and he really should look in to `$.get` and `$.post`.

Comment: Ahh, it can get confusing when things are deleted, I think they should <so> the deleted commends and minimise deleted answers ^_^. I hope user1647423 can fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon. I'm not sure what you guys are talking about (something was deleted?... not sure how I can fix the issue Richard). I will look into $.post and then perhaps I will need to look further into your answer Jon. Thanks very much to both of you - I would appreciate if any of you could recommend a good site about this that isn't too technical. I've searched and read so much already but most pages fails to explain the most basic stuff.

Comment: Well firstly, don't worry too much about security unless you're dealing with money. jQuery is just a library of function scripted in Javascript. - So I recommend understanding how Javascript actively run's on your page from [ http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp ] and then progress on to [ http://www.jquery.com ] for jQuery.